# How to send contents of a webrtc stream directly to my server?

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc

I've recently started getting into webRTC and would like to stream my webcam to my web server.  However, I can only seem to find concrete examples of doing this peer to peer.

I know the very basics:

```js
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(stream) {
  // I want to send the output of this stream object to my server 
}
```

Can anyone give a rough example of how this would be done?

Comment: but webRTC is peer to peer... you can find clients for some server platforms, like nodejs

Comment: I understand that... but I want to leverage the user media capture elements of webRTC, which I can't find anywhere else without using plugins.  So are you saying there's no way to send this stream anywhere but another webRTC enabled browser?

Comment: @Matthias have you looked at kurento media server?

Comment: Hey Mido.  I started looking into it yesterday evening - many thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to sending a WebRTC stream to the server is to pass an answer SDP to your peer connection that includes an address/port combination that directs the WebRTC media streams to a server. Its common with Media Resources Function (MRF) like Dialogics XMS server to route a media stream to the server for things like record/playback, transcoding and multi-way mixing/tiling. MRFs can generate an answer to a WebRTC client offer that includes all the necessary addresses and ports and many MRFs also support ICE for alternate media stream routing. If you want to have strict control over this you'll need to learn how to manipulate session descriptions (SDPs).

In general, you need to call:

peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(SdpObserver observer, SessionDescription sdp);

with the proper answer SDP to control where the WebRTC peer connection will send the media streams

Comment: Thanks Bpulito - I was confused whether or not I could send the stream via websockets, but this has clarified the problem for me.

Comment: You're welcome! Media is sent by the WebRTC peer connection using SRTP over DTLS. Its highly secure and you'll need to make sure that your server-side endpoint supports DTLS/SRTP. The SDP contain the encryption keys for SRTP and I believe DTLS is negotiated via the media itself. Take a look at www.wasdev.com/webrtc if you are looking for a quick way to get a WebRTC solution off the ground. Its free for developers and small single-server deployments. We do a lot of work with MRFs from Dialogic and Radisys as well.